# How many html files does Meteor render inside client directory?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I had a main.html inside client folder with many menus,header, footer etc. I also declared a `div` inside it to be rendered by a component.

```
...
 <div id="render-slides"></div>
 ...
```

And my main.js:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'animate.css/animate.min.css'
import '../imports/css/sidebar.css';
//import './imports/js/nodcast.js';
//import './main.html';

import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import '../imports/startup/accounts-config.js';
import App from '../imports/ui/App.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('render-slides'));
});
```

It rendered the slides from the component, but I couldn't click on them as if they were covered with other divs. So, I entirely replaced my main.html with:

```
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="render-slides"></div>
</body>
```

And renamed my old `main.html` to `main2.html`. As I run the program, it shows my render slides inside the old structure (menuse, ...) in main2.html and I don't have the problem of clicking!!!

However, if I move `main2.html` I just have a blank html files containing the rendered components. Note in both html files I have the `<div id="render-slides"></div>`. So, I wonder how it works! Does it merege all html files inside client directory and render them together?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it merege all html files inside client directory and render them together?!!

Yes, that is the default eager loading behaviour of Meteor. Furthermore, anything named "main" is loaded last, so that is why your old "main2.html" file appears first, and its id is picked up first to render your slides within.

> Meteor will load all files outside of any directory named `imports/` in the application using the default file load order rules

See https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order